# GoogleMapReact - Unable to dynamically add markers on the Map

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-redux

I have a basic React.js project in which I am using GoogleMapReact component ([reference](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react)). There is a button on the page which should add a custom defined component on top of the map at a random location. The code for the same is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => (
  <div
    style={{
      color: 'white',
      background: 'grey',
      padding: '15px 10px',
      display: 'inline-flex',
      textAlign: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      borderRadius: '100%',
      transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </div>
);

const SimpleMap = ({ center, zoom, markers }) => {
    console.log(markers)
  return (
    <GoogleMapReact defaultCenter={center} defaultZoom={0}
     bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: "MY_KEY-sxt-h" }}>
      {markers.map((marker, index) => (
        <AnyReactComponent
          key={index}
          lat={marker.lat}
          lng={marker.lng}
          text={marker.text}
        />
      ))}
    </GoogleMapReact>
  );
};

const Temp = () => {
  const [markers, setMarkers] = useState([
    { lat: 59.955413, lng: 30.337844, text: 'Kreyser Avrora' },
    { lat: 57.955413, lng: 32.337844, text: 'Kreyser Avrora' }
  ]);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    const randomLat = Math.random() * 33;
    const randomLng = Math.random() * 33;
    const newMarker = {
      lat: randomLat,
      lng: randomLng,
      text: 'Random Marker'
    };

    setMarkers((prevMarkers) => [...prevMarkers, newMarker]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ width: '100%', height: '400px' }}>
        <SimpleMap center={{ lat: 59.95, lng: 30.33 }} zoom={11} markers={markers} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Add Marker</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Temp;
```

Now, when I press the button, nothing happens to the DOM. I have verified using console.log() commands that the props (and thus the state) of the SimpleMap component is changing. However these extra s are not being added to the DOM. I have also tried using React Developer Tools and the Chrome debugger. Every render works as expected, however these components aren't being added to the DOM. Any help will be highly appreciated! Thank you :)

I have verified using console.log() commands that the props (and thus the state) of the SimpleMap component is changing. However these extra s are not being added to the DOM. I have also tried using React Developer Tools and the Chrome debugger. Every render works as expected, however these components aren't being added to the DOM.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this? A working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) that reproduces this issue would be great!